# browser-sync でカレントディレクトリ以下にないファイルも監視したい

Tags: command-line, browser-sync

カレントディレクトリの兄弟ディレクトリも`browser-sync`の監視対象にしたいです。

下記のコマンドで、兄弟ディレクトリにあるcssの変更も監視対象になると思ったのですが、cssの変更があっても反応しません。

```
dest-after>browser-sync start --server --files ../*
```

---

下記サイトで質問をしていた内容と関連した質問です。
https://teratail.com/questions/54590

---

下記の通り、回答に従いましたが、反応しませんでした。

```
dest-after>browser-sync start --server --files '../**/*'
```

Comment: すいません。余計なものがついていましたね。こちらです。

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/54590

Comment: postcssをつかっているので、

Comment: src-beforeにトランスパイル前の、cssがあり、

Comment: dest-afterにトランスパイル後のcssとhtml、画像

Comment: などがあります。gulp初心者なので、このような構成にするのが正しくないのかがわかっていません。

Comment: もし、destにトランスパイル前のpostcssを入れても、トランスパイルしてくれるならそれでもいいですが、
トランスパイルしたいCSSはbeforeに入れないといけないルールなんですよね？
もしかしてそこから認識違いなのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
browser-sync start --server --files '../**/*'
```

とすれば、親ディレクトリ以下の全てのファイルの変更を監視します。

`--files` に渡すパスは確か[`glob`モジュール](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob)によって解釈されます。
パターンには数種の記法が使えますが、この場合は `**` を使えばよいです。
これで、サブディレクトリ以下も再帰的にマッチします。

---

本題とずれますが、殆どの用途では `browser-sync` で提供しないファイルを監視する必要は無い、という事を申し添えておきます。
つまり、上記のようなことが必要になったならば、何か間違えている可能性が高いです。

---

追記:
あまり詳しくないですが、Windows のシェルだとシングルクォーテーションではなく、ダブルクォーテーションを使うべきなのかもしれません。
`--files "../**/*"` のように。

Comment: ここに記載すると見にくいので編集をしました