# sourcemapsをpostcssで使うことはできないのでしょうか？

Tags: javascript, gulp

sourcemapsをpostcssで使うことはできないのでしょうか？
日本語の情報もほとんど見つかりません。

---

使用を試みると、下記のエラーが出ます。

・実行結果

```
>gulp sourcemaps
(node:5620) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.
[18:26:30] Using gulpfile ~\Desktop\images\gulp-folder\website\aaa\gulpfile.js
[18:26:30] Starting 'sourcemaps'...
[18:26:30] 'sourcemaps' errored after 71 ms
[18:26:30] Error in plugin 'gulp-postcss'
Message:
    Please provide array of postcss processors!
[18:27:16] ReferenceError: css is not defined
```

・`gulpfile.js`

```
// //gulpfile.js
var gulp = require('gulp');              //gulpをインポート
var postcssimport = require('postcss-import');
var postcss = require('gulp-postcss');   //gulp-postcssをインポート
var cssnext = require('postcss-cssnext'); //cssnextをインポート
var nested = require('postcss-nested');
var csswring = require('csswring');
var calc = require('postcss-calc');
// var comment = require('postcss-comment');
var customProperties = require("postcss-custom-properties");
var customMedia = require("postcss-custom-media"); //うまくいっていない。カスタムメディアクエリーズが使える
var sourcemaps = require("gulp-sourcemaps");
// var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();


gulp.task('css', function () {           //”css”タスクを登録
  var plugins = [
  postcssimport,
  cssnext,                      //一旦空の配列を作成
  nested,
  calc,
  csswring,
  // comment,
  customProperties,
  // customMedia,
  // browserSync
   ];

// returnは上から順番にプラグインを実行していくという意味
  return gulp.src(
    ['./src-before/*.css' , './src-before/*/*.css'],
    { base: 'src-before' })         //src-before下にある.cssファイルを指定
    .pipe(postcss(plugins))              //PostCSSにファイルを処理してもらう
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dest-after/css'));          //生成されたCSSをdest-after下に配置
});

gulp.task("sourcemaps", function () {
  gulp.src(['./src-before/*.css' , './src-before/*/*.css'])
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init()) 
    .pipe(postcss())   //postcssのコンパイル
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write("./"))  
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./src-before/"));   
});
```

Comment: nodejsがわからない初心者なので、恐縮ですがその方法がわからず質問させてもらいました。

おそらく下記がcssに渡している配列のことだと思いますが、
gulp.task('css', function () {           //”css”タスクを登録
  var plugins = [

下記でpostcssに渡しているつもりでしたが渡せていないのでしょうか？
.pipe(postcss(plugins))

下記のようにするということですか？
gulp.task('postcss', function () {          
  var plugins = [
postcssimport,
  cssnext,                      //一旦空の配列を作成
  nested,
  calc,
  csswring,
  // comment,
  customProperties,
  // customMedia,
  // browserSync
   ];

Comment: 初心者なので、具体的なソースコードを示してもらえませんか

Comment: そうでないと同じ事になる可能性が高いので。

Comment: そもそも何故複数タスクに分けているのでしょう…(変換前のファイル上書きしますよねこれ…

Comment: ありがとうございます。
すると下記でよいのですね。

gulp.task("sourcemaps", function () {
  gulp.src(['./src-before/*.css' , './src-before/*/*.css'])
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init()) 
    .pipe(postcss(plugins))   //postcssのコンパイル
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write("./"))  
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./src-before/"));   
});

Comment: 確かにエラー内容がかわりました。

C:\Users\ho\Desktop\images\gulp-folder\website\aaa>gulp sourcemaps
(node:4784) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.
[21:35:36] Using gulpfile ~\Desktop\images\gulp-folder\website\aaa\gulpfile.js
[21:35:36] Task 'sourcemaps' is not in your gulpfile
[21:35:36] Please check the documentation for proper gulpfile formatting

ただしエラーがそれでも出ます。

Comment: ここで上書きされるということですか？
.pipe(postcss(plugins))   //postcssのコンパイル

Comment: ただソースマップもcssタスクに含めてしまうと、トランスパイルをするごとに毎度マップを作ってしまいませんか
ほとんど速度が変わらないならよいですが。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> sourcemapsをpostcssで使うことはできないのでしょうか？

使用出来ます。
公式の README でも `gulp`の使用例では、`gulp-sourcemaps`が使われています。
https://github.com/postcss/postcss#gulp

```
gulp.task('css', function () {
    var postcss    = require('gulp-postcss');
    var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

    return gulp.src('src/**/*.css')
        .pipe( sourcemaps.init() )
        .pipe( postcss([ require('autoprefixer'), require('precss') ]) )
        .pipe( sourcemaps.write('.') )
        .pipe( gulp.dest('build/') );
});
```

---

以下蛇足ですが、質問者が直面しているエラーの解決に役立てば幸いです。

質問者の`css`タスクから`sourcemaps` タスクを作成すると下記のようになります。
注: 変なコメントなどもそのままです。内容が理解出来ない場合は**実行しないで下さい**。大事なファイルが消えてしまった、などの事態に**責任は一切負えません**。

```
gulp.task('sourcemaps', function () {
  var plugins = [
  postcssimport,
  cssnext,                      //一旦空の配列を作成
  nested,
  calc,
  csswring,
  // comment,
  customProperties,
  // customMedia,
  // browserSync
   ];

// returnは上から順番にプラグインを実行していくという意味
  return gulp.src(
    ['./src-before/*.css' , './src-before/*/*.css'],
    { base: 'src-before' })         //src-before下にある.cssファイルを指定
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init()) 
    .pipe(postcss(plugins))              //PostCSSにファイルを処理してもらう
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write("./"))  
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dest-after/css'));          //生成されたCSSをdest-after下に配置
});
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。
ただ下記のようにすでにその記載はあるように思えるのですが、これが理由なのでしょうか？

gulp.task("sourcemaps", function () {
  return gulp.src(['./src-before/*.css' , './src-before/*/*.css'])
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init()) 
    .pipe(postcss(plugins))   //postcssのコンパイル
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write("./"))  
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./dest-after"));   
});

Comment: .pipe(sourcemaps.write("./"))  // マップファイルを出力するパスを指定します
と聞いたのですがこの認識でよいでしょうか？
するとそのあとのdestは出力先ではないのでしょうか？

Comment: ・ディレクトリ構成は下記のようになっています。
gulpfile.js、dest-after、src-beforeは同じディレクトリ内にあります。



C:.
├─dest-after
│  ├─css
│  │  ├─foundation
│  │  ├─layout
│  │  └─object
│  │      ├─component
│  │      ├─project
│  │      └─utility
│  ├─html
│  ├─img
│  │  ├─common-img
│  │  └─index
│  ├─js
│  ├─plugin
│  └─web-font
├─node_modules
│  ├─.bin
│  ├─abbrev
│
│
│
｜─src-before
│  ├─css
│  │  ├─foundation
│  │  ├─layout
│  │  └─object
│  │      ├─component
│  │      ├─project
│  │      └─utility

Comment: gulp.task("sourcemaps", function () {
  return gulp.src(['./src-before/*.css' , './src-before/*/*.css'])
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init()) 
    .pipe(postcss())   //postcssのコンパイル
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write("./"))  // マップファイルを出力するパスを指定します
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./src-before/"));
});
上記のようにしましたが

Comment: かきのようにえらーになりました
>gulp sourcemaps
(node:9300) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.
[17:39:52] Using gulpfile ~\Desktop\images\gulp-folder\website\aaa\gulpfile.js
[17:39:52] Starting 'sourcemaps'...
[17:39:52] 'sourcemaps' errored after 55 ms
[17:39:52] Error in plugin 'gulp-postcss'
Message:
    Please provide array of postcss processors!

Comment: gulp.task("sourcemaps", function () {
  // 変わっている。plugins の定義があったはず

  gulp.src(['./src-before/*.css' , './src-before/*/*.css']) // 変わっている。{ base: 'src-before' }) が無くなっている
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init()) 
    .pipe(postcss()) // 変わっている。plugins を引数で渡していたはず
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write("./"))  
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./src-before/"));  // 変わっている。dest-after/css だったはず
});
をそのままコピペすればよいのですか

Comment: 追加とは下記の追加と記載してある部分だと思いますが
gulp.task('css', function() {
    var list = [1, 2, 3];
    gulp.src('src/**/*.css')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())  // 追加
        .pipe(plugin1())
        .pipe(plugin2(list))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write()) // 追加
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dest'));
});

下記にもすでに書いていませんか？

Comment: gulp.task("sourcemaps", function () {
  // 変わっている。plugins の定義があったはず

  gulp.src(['./src-before/*.css' , './src-before/*/*.css']) // 変わっている。{ base: 'src-before' }) が無くなっている
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init()) 
    .pipe(postcss()) // 変わっている。plugins を引数で渡していたはず
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write("./"))  
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./src-before/"));  // 変わっている。dest-after/css だったはず
});

Comment: もしかして下記を変更するということですか？

gulp.task('css', function () {           //”css”タスクを登録
  var plugins = [
  postcssimport,
  cssnext,                      //一旦空の配列を作成
  sourcemaps,
  nested,
  calc,
  csswring
  // comment,
  // customProperties
  // customMedia,
  // browserSync
   ];

// returnは上から順番にプラグインを実行していくという意味
})

Comment: 理由はわかりませんができました。大変ありがとうございました。後ほど再コメントさせてもらいます

Comment: もしお時間があることがありましたら、大変恐縮ですが、
http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/30500/browser-sync%e3%81%ae%e3%82%ab%e3%83%ac%e3%83%b3%e3%83%88%e3%81%ab%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84%e3%83%95%e3%82%a1%e3%82%a4%e3%83%ab%e3%81%8c%e3%81%86%e3%81%be%e3%81%8f%e6%8c%87%e5%ae%9a%e3%81%a7%e3%81%8d%e3%81%be%e3%81%9b%e3%82%93
のbrowser-syncがうまくいかない件もご覧になっていただけるとありがたいです。

Comment: http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/30887/%e3%83%96%e3%83%a9%e3%82%a6%e3%82%b6%e3%83%bc%e3%82%b7%e3%83%b3%e3%82%af%e3%81%ab%e3%81%a4%e3%81%84%e3%81%a6-index-html%e3%81%a0%e3%81%91%e3%83%aa%e3%83%ad%e3%83%bc%e3%83%89%e3%81%97%e3%81%a6%e3%81%8f%e3%82%8c%e3%81%a6css%e3%81%af%e3%81%97%e3%81%a6%e3%81%8f%e3%82%8c%e3%81%be%e3%81%9b%e3%82%93
に新しく再質問しました。

Comment: 下記のように、var sourcemaps = require("gulp-sourcemaps");を読み込ませるようにしたところ、
エラーが出ます。

gulp.task('sourcemaps', function () {
  var plugins = [
  postcssimport,
  cssnext,                      //一旦空の配列を作成
  nested,
  calc,
  csswring,
  sourcemaps
  // comment,
  //customProperties,
  // customMedia,
  // browserSync
   ];

プラグインはすべて上記で読み込ませないといけないと思っていたのですが、
そうではないのでしょうか？
どのように区別するのですかね？

下記のようにエラーが出ました。
throw new Error(i + ' is not a PostCSS plugin');
Error: [object Object] is not a PostCSS plugin

Comment: ・また、下記ようにしないといけないのは、cssnextをこちらで実行しないといけなかったからでしょうか？
それだと他はひつようないですね。
gulp.task('sourcemaps', function () {
  var plugins = [
  postcssimport,
  cssnext,                      //一旦空の配列を作成
  nested,
  calc,
  csswring
  // comment,
  //customProperties,
  // customMedia,
  // browserSync
   ];

別質問にしたほうが良いですかね？

Comment: @web 別質問の方がよいです。コメントではソースが読めませんし、他の方の目にもとまりませんから。（また、必要無くなったコメントは削除してしまっていいと思いますよ。結果としてQ6Aが残ればよいので）