# ブラウザシンクの続き

Tags: gulp

[Gulp で起動した BrowserSync に出力先ディレクトリの更新時にもれなくリロードさせたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/30887/%e3%83%96%e3%83%a9%e3%82%a6%e3%82%b6%e3%83%bc%e3%82%b7%e3%83%b3%e3%82%af%e3%81%ab%e3%81%a4%e3%81%84%e3%81%a6-index-html%e3%81%a0%e3%81%91%e3%83%aa%e3%83%ad%e3%83%bc%e3%83%89%e3%81%97%e3%81%a6%e3%81%8f%e3%82%8c%e3%81%a6css%e3%81%af%e3%81%97%e3%81%a6%e3%81%8f%e3%82%8c%e3%81%be%e3%81%9b%e3%82%93)
の続き

別質問にしたほうが良いということなので、こちらにしました。

・ディレクトリ構成

```
C:.
├─dest-after
│ ├─css
│ │ ├─foundation
│ │ ├─layout
│ │ └─object
│ │ ├─component
│ │ ├─project
│ │ └─utility
│ ├─html
│ ├─img
│ │ ├─common-img
│ │ └─index
│ ├─js
│ ├─plugin
│ └─web-font
├─node_modules
│ ├─.bin
│ ├─abbrev
│ ├─accepts
│ │ └─node_modules
│ │ ├─mime-db
│ │ └─mime-types
```

・トランスパイル前のpostcssはdest-afterフォルダと同じディレクトリないにあります。

・ちなみに下記コマンドはdest-afterフォルダをカレントとして実行しているので、
dest-after>browser-sync start --server --files "../src-before/foundation/*, index.html"

baseDir: "./" も
gulp.watch ("../src-before/foundation/*", function ()も
両方ともdest-afterをカレントとして相対パスを記載すればよいのですよね？

下記でとりあえずリロードはしました。
ただ元のソースでどの部分に問題があったかはまだはっきりしません。

```
gulp.watch(['dest-after/', 'src-before/' , 'src-before//' , 'src-before///*']).on('change', browserSync.reload);
});
```

の部分の訂正が効果的だったのでしょうか？
検証をしてみますが、ここが問題だったのだろうとおわかりでしたらそこを試してみたいので教えてください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gulp.watch` のファイル指定に問題があったようです。以下のように指定して解決しました。

```
gulp.watch (['dest-after/index.html','dest-after/**/*', 'src-before/**' , 'src-before/**/*' , 'src-before/**/**/*'], function () { 
            browserSync.reload();
    });
```