# gulpfile.js で BrowserSync を使用すると "is not a PostCSS plugin" というエラーが出る

Tags: gulp, browser-sync

`gulpfile.js` にて Browser Sync を使用しています。

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var postcss = require('gulp-postcss');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

// 略

gulp.task('default', function () { 
    var plugins = [
       postcssimport,
       cssnext,
       nested,
       calc,
       // browserSync
    ];

// 略
     .pipe(postcss(plugins))              //PostCSSにファイルを処理してもらう
```

上記の `// browserSync` の `//` を外して有効にすると下記のエラーが出るのですが、なぜbrowserSyncのプラグインを読み込むと下記のエラーが出るのでしょうか？
browserSyncは読み込みは不要でしてはいけないのでしょうか？
ここで読み込まなくてもbrowserSyncは使えています。

```
throw new Error(i + ' is not a PostCSS plugin');     ^
Error: [object Object] is not a PostCSS plugin
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browser Sync は PostCSS のプラグインではないからです。
基本的には何のプラグインでもありません。

`browser-sync` モジュールは、開発用のサーバを作成する為の API と、単独で動作するコマンドの両方を提供します。
API は Gulp と協調して動作させるのに便利な機能があり、他のモジュールを介さず`gulpfile.js` で使用されますが、Gulp 専用のプラグインというわけではなく、ましてや、PostCSS、Sass などのプラグインではないです。

---

質問のコードの `plugins` 変数は `postcss` への引数として用意されたもので、PostCSS のプラグインをまとめておく為に用意した物だったはずです。
編集しているうちに意図を忘れてしまったのでしょう。

私が[以前の回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/30890/3054)で下記のように`cssPlugins` という変数名を用いたのは、こういった勘違いを防ぐ為です。

```
const cssPlugins = [
    require('postcss-import'),
    require('postcss-cssnext'),
    require('postcss-nested'),
    require('csswring'),
    require('postcss-calc'),
    require("postcss-custom-properties"),
];
```

Comment: 見様見真似で行っているのでまさかpostcssのプラグインでないとは思いませんでした。sass

Comment: プラグインだったということですかね。
また、その後ブラウザシンク自体はおかげさまでできたのですが、
postcssをセーブしても、下記が実行されずにリロードはするがcssの変更が適応されないようになりました。
疲れました。

var plugins = [
  postcssimport,
  cssnext,                      //一旦空の配列を作成
  nested,
  calc,
  csswring,
  customProperties
  // customMedia,
  // browserSyncという記載は必要ない
     ];

Comment: また再質問させてもらいます。おそらくこれで出来上がると思いますので、恐縮ですがよろしくお願いいたします。